# PHP Send Request Header not Sent Response NULL

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

i have a problem when send request header to my restful, my restful checking request Authorize header, but when i send the header is missing.

My restful debug give me result `NULL`
i was tried to add CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER but also not working , 
anyone can help me out ? 
here is my code :

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://mysitehttps.domain",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asdasd\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: 123HaHaHa",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "postman-token: 3b3fd06d-a8aa-65db-a917-c911fa0bb5d5"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: did you try to CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true?

Comment: yes, but didn't work , any idea for solving it sir ?

Comment: may i know your real url and all the code??

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code and its working for me.
Your content-type is set to multi-part. Are you sure its not json. anyway try the code below

```
//initialize data variables that you want to send as post below

$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('https://mysitehttps.domain');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    //'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),

"Authorization: 123HaHaHa",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "postman-token: 3b3fd06d-a8aa-65db-a917-c911fa0bb5d5"


)                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: what is it that you are posting, Can we have the full code of yours so that i can better find the solution